# Why does my Nuxt/Tailwindcss app have a 12 pixel white bar at the top, above <html>?

Tags: tailwind-css, nuxt-content, nuxt3

I'm working on a blog using Nuxt 3, Nuxt-content, and Tailwind-css. I just set the background color in my `app.vue` and noticed there's a 12-pixel white bar above my content. The weird thing is, looking in Chrome dev tools, the entire `<body>` element is shifted down by 12 pixels! The `<html>` element starts at y=0, and I've never seen anything like that.

I don't think I've got any strange `:before` CSS but since I'm using tailwindcss, it could be anywhere.

It's a whole app, so I can't paste it here, but I made a Stackblitz so you can see it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zgbqga?file=README.md
(It should do `yarn install && yarn dev` when you load it up.)

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: In the `default.vue` layout you've set `m-3` class on `article` tag

Comment: Wow, that fixes it! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. (Especially if you can explain why it ends up moving the whole body down!!)